# General questions about data transfer in Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*When I say "transfer" I am referring only to billable transferred data, which I believe is downloaded data only.*

Lets say you're listening to `ref('/posts/').onValue()` and then you call `ref('/posts').once()`, does Realtime Database know to transfer no data across the network because the client already has the most up-to-date version of the data?

Now lets say you're listening to `ref('/posts/').onValue()` and a new update is found. Does Realtime Database transfer the delta or the entire document?

Now lets say you are doing a filter like `ref('/posts/').orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(10)` and your `/posts/` ref has 500 entries. Does Realtime Database transfer 10 children to the client or all 500?

Now lets say you register thousands of listeners with Realtime Database, are you billed for the setting and removal of listeners?

*Note: I'm not sure if this should be multiple questions or if this shouldn't be posted on Stack Overflow. Such is the uncertainty of a stack newbie.*

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/905ov9/general_questions_about_realtime_database/

Answer (score 2):

If you attach multiple listeners to a location at the same time, the data for that location will only be transferred once.

When there is an update to a part of a larger node that you listen to, Firebase tries to send only the delta over the wire. The size of the exact data depends on the total size of the node and the update under it.

If you have an index on the queried property, only the query results will be transferred. If you don't have an index on the property, the Firebase client will log an error, transfer all data at the location and filter client-side.

Note that there are tools to learn about these things:

1. Use the [Firebase Database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) to learn more about read/write speed, bandwidth, and unindexed queries.
2. [Enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) or check the network tab of your browser to see the exact wire traffic between the client and the database.